# Selenium WebDriver в отдельном окне?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

При использовании WebDriver (в частности ChromeDriver) в консольном приложении, сталкиваюсь с нежелательными побочными эффектами его работы. Если вывод какой-то своей информации в окно консоли еще не мешает, то остановка работы программы до вызова у драйвера метода Quit, мешает очень сильно. Собственно, возможно ли выделить ему отдельное окно?

Comment: `остановка работы программы до вызова у драйвера метода Quit` ?? Может у Вас просто ошибка в коде?

Comment: У меня программа использует WebDriver для получения данных, но в то же время должна делать какие-то действия в определенное время, и я столкнулся с тем, что без полного закрытия (Quit) драйвера перестают работать даже таймеры и задачи.

Comment: Запускать драйвер в отдельном потоке/процессе?

Comment: Как Вам уже сказал мой тёзка, вам нужно смотреть в сторону запуска различных заданий в разных потоках.